# Open messages in Bootstrap modal

Tags: 8, theming

I use bootstrap theme, and I want to open messages in bootstrap modal; after searching, I found the [Bootstrap Modal Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_modal_messages) module, which is not available for Drupal 8.

Is there any way for Drupal messages to appear in a Bootstrap modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by twig template and jquery. Add only 'Status messages' block on 'Highlighted' region. and in the twig template add like below:

```
{% if page.highlighted %}
          {% block highlighted %}

            <div class="modal fade" id="modal-div">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Message</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    {{ page.highlighted }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}
```

After that in jquery file :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    if($.trim($("#modal-div .region-highlighted").text()) != ''){//region will be printed even if the highlighted area is blank
        $('#modal-div').modal('show');
    }
});
```

This will show your messages in modal window.

Comment: finally I did it with something like this

Comment: @YusefMohamadi, can you post the final solution?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal at the end of the day outputs HTML just like any other non Drupal site.

If you look at the [Modal Messages Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) all you have to do is add modal html attributes (ex: `data-toggle="modal"` or `class="modal fade"`) to your Drupal message divs.

If you look at the D7 module, all the "[magic](https://i.imgur.com/vPtZp3G.gif)" (adding the attributes) is done through jQuery.

---

Alternatively, you can add the attributes by adding the following to your **themename.theme** file

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  if (!empty($variables['page']['highlighted'])) {
    $variables['page']['highlighted']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'modal fade';
    $variables['page']['highlighted']['#attributes']['data-toggle'][] = 'modal';
  }
}
```

The above will work as long as your `Status messages` block is placed in the Highlighted region in `/admin/structure/block`.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: no worked, I test it right now , not worked ,